# flutter ios Simulator keeps crashing after installing firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having a problem running my flutter project on ios simulator after installing firebase. I think this may be due to something I need to set in cloud console or maybe xcode?

I'm using vscode. I'm not getting any errors in the console, however simulator just abruptly stops.

When I do `flutter run` this is what I get:

```
(base) juliapak@julias-MacBook-Air coffeesociety % flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on iphone 14 promax in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                        20.4s
Xcode build done.                                           47.3s
(base) juliapak@julias-MacBook-Air coffeesociety %
```

[image: results of flutter run]

I think it may have something to do with google cloud console, however I do not recall how to resolve this. When I mouse over the red x in vscode terminal it just says error code 1.